# After clicked login button no operation done

Tags: reactjs

I trying to do a project,actually it is running..But after clicking the login button no actions taking place like if it is a wrong password or username no messages show same for if we type the correct password and username..
this my code
page.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import LoggedOut from '../components/LoggedOut';
    import LoggedIn from '../components/LoggedIn';
    import config from '../config';

    const defaultFetchOptions = {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      }
    };

    class Page extends Component {
      constructor() {
        super();

        this.state = {
          userLoggedIn: false,
          errorMessage: '',
          userId: null
        }
        this.logUserIn = this.logUserIn.bind(this);
      }

      parseLogInResponse({user = {}}) {
        if (user.success) {
          this.setState({
            userLoggedIn: true,
            userId: user.id
          });
        } else {
          this.setState({
            errorMessage: 'Sorry that wasnt correct'
          })
        }
      }

      logUserIn(username, password) {
        const fetchOptions = Object.assign({}, defaultFetchOptions);
        fetchOptions.body = JSON.stringify({
          username: username,
          password: password
        });
        return fetch(config.USER_URL, fetchOptions)
          .then(results => results.json())
          .then(response => this.parseLogInResponse(response));
      }

      render() {
        return (
          <div>
            {this.state.userLoggedIn ?
              (<LoggedIn userId={this.state.userId} />) :
              (<LoggedOut errorMessage={this.state.errorMessage} logUserIn={this.logUserIn} />)
            }
          </div>
        )
      }
    }

    export default Page;
```

LoggedOut.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from "prop-types";


class LoggedOut extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      username: '',
      password: ''
    }

    this.loginHandler = this.loginHandler.bind(this);
    this.handleUsernameChange = this.handleChange.bind(this, 'username');
    this.handlePasswordChange = this.handleChange.bind(this, 'password');
  }

  handleChange(property, event) {
    this.setState({
      [property]: event.target.value
    });
  }

  loginHandler(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.logUserIn(this.state.username, this.state.password);
  }

  render() {
    const { errorMessage } = this.props;

    return (
      <div>
        {errorMessage ? <p>{errorMessage}</p> : null}
        <form action="/check-login" method="post">
                     <div>
                                <label>email/user ID</label>
                                <div>
                                   <input id='username' 
                                   name="username" 
                                   value={this.state.username} 
                                   placeholder="Enter Username"
                                   onChange={this.handleUsernameChange} />
                                </div>


                                <label>password</label>
                                <div>
                                     <input id='password' 
                                     name="password" 
                                     value={this.state.password}
                                     placeholder="Enter Password"
                                     onChange={this.handlePasswordChange}  
                                     type="password" />

                                </div>
                       </div>

            <button title="Log in" onClick={this.loginHandler} type="submit">Log in</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default LoggedOut;
```

LoggedIn.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class LoggedIn extends  Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        Thanks for logging in {this.props.userId}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default LoggedIn;
```

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import PageContainer from './containers/Page';
import './index.css';

ReactDOM.render(
  <PageContainer />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Why my code shows this error?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It is helpful if you provide the details of the error. Simply providing your code and asking "why doesn't this work" is a bit hard, as there are so many other environmental things at play.

Comment: You asked why your code shows this error... what error?

Comment: sorry I meant it doesn't work properly by clicking in login button

Comment: Please show us the error. "Doesn`t work properly" is not very specific you know.

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is that you cannot attach to the `onClick` of a `submit` button. Instead you need to bind to the `onSubmit` of the `form`. So, you might do something like this:

```
<form action="/check-login" method="post" onSubmit={this.loginHandler}>
    ...
</form>
```

Furthermore, remove the `onClick` that's attached to the button:

```
<button title="Log in" type="submit">Log in</button>
```

Comment: Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch... in console tis errorr is shown.. Why??

Comment: @lex that would be a completely different error. The click *is working now.* You now have a separate issue retrieving data. The `fetch` is failing. In short, the target URL can't be found.